# Using AWS SNS with Angular in a static two-tier application

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-sns

I am working on this static website created with Angular. I want to make it possible for users visiting website to drop a inquiry message which should then be delivered to a specific mobile number (or couple of numbers).

Its a static website with no backend till now, so I have decided to go as a two-tier application with AWS at the backend. Now, I have worked with Angular but I am new to AWS.

I read across different articles and videos:

[AWS SNS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/push-notifications-to-mobile-devices-using-amazon-sns/)
[AWS SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/welcome.html)

I have installed the npm package for `aws-sdk`, imported it in the angular project but I am unable to figure out how to use the sdk for specific services. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any tutorials/blog describing usage of SNS with Angular.

Can someone please direct me to any such tutorial or documentation of using SNS with Angular.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example how to publish message to SNS:
[SNS example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/sns-examples-publishing-messages.html)

```
// Load the AWS SDK for Node.js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
// Set region
AWS.config.update({region: 'REGION'});

// Create publish parameters
var params = {
  Message: 'MESSAGE_TEXT', /* required */
  TopicArn: 'TOPIC_ARN'
};

// Create promise and SNS service object
var publishTextPromise = new AWS.SNS({apiVersion: '2010-03-31'}).publish(params).promise();

// Handle promise's fulfilled/rejected states
publishTextPromise.then(
  function(data) {
    console.log(`Message ${params.Message} send sent to the topic ${params.TopicArn}`);
    console.log("MessageID is " + data.MessageId);
 }).catch(
    function(err) {
    console.error(err, err.stack);
 });
```